# Memory issues in recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, depth-first-search

I'm trying to solve this leetcode problem here: https://leetcode.com/problems/next-closest-time/description/.

Simply my solution is to try every combination that is valid and then set my ans variable to the one that is closest to the original time. It does print out all the combinations however the diff variable never changes. In the for loop after (if cur.length ==4) it prints every possible combination because it still thinks that diff is 9007199254740991. Also when I assign ans to cur.slice(), I receive a blank array.  Even when I uncomment it in the nextClosestTime function I still have the same issue.

```
/**
 * @param {string} time
 * @return {string}
 */

var diff = 9007199254740991;

function calcSeconds(digits) {
  var hours = (digits[0] * 10) + digits[1];
  var seconds = (digits[2] * 10) + digits[3];

  return (hours * 3600) + (seconds * 60);
}


function nextClosestTime(time) {

  var digits = [];
  // diff = 9007199254740991; 

  var cur = [];
  var ans = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
    if (isFinite(time.charAt(i))) {
      digits.push(parseInt(time.charAt(i)));
    }
  }

  var target = calcSeconds(digits);

  nch(digits, cur, diff, target, ans);

  return ans;

};


function nch(digits, cur, diff, target, ans) {
  if (cur.length == 4) {

    var curSec = calcSeconds(cur);
    if (Math.abs(curSec - target) < diff) {
      console.log(cur);
      diff = Math.abs(calcSeconds(digits) - calcSeconds(cur));
      //ans = cur.slice();
    }
    return;

  }

  for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    if ((((cur[0] * 10) + cur[1]) >= 24) || (((cur[2] * 10) + cur[3]) >= 60)) {
      return;
    }

    cur.push(digits[i]);
    nch(digits, cur, diff, target, ans);
    cur.pop()
  }


}
```

Comment: I see no recursion - nevermind ... scrolled down :p The `diff` argument to `nch` isn't the same variable as the "global" var called `diff`

Comment: even when i fix that there's still an error, I'm just trying to get the diff variable to change and stay changed